# MongoDB how can we have all the admin privileges plus restriction to access the data inside the database

Tags: mongodb

We need to know how we can restrict having access to MongoDB even when we have admin access. we as devops create MongoDB then we get admin access, using these admin access we can see data in all database in MongoDB . How can we restrict read and write data in all database in MongoDB This user requires to perform all admin tasks and access to infra.But, as xyz being GDPR complaint, We should not have access to customer’s data . So, we need solution that this user can perform any admin activity but it should not able to access to customer’s data and can you provide links for this as well.

Comment: What kind of admin work you need to do?

Comment: user creation , monitoring ,DB autoscaling policy change

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Built-In Roles](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/built-in-roles/). Should be possible to create admin user and grant only required privileges.

Mayor problem could be task user creation. An admin user with `userAdmin` role for a database can assign themselves any privilege on that database.

Apart from that, an admin can simply take a copy of the database files and run the copy (even without any authentication at all) on his personal computer, i.e. read all data. You can encrypt the database files ([Encryption at Rest](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-encryption-at-rest/)), however an admin user with access to MongoDB process owner also has access to this encryption key.

The only solution would be the [Client-Side Field Level Encryption](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/csfle/)